# Java - How to Configure LDAP Authentication?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ldap

I want to use LDAP Authentication to login the system. And I configure ldap properties with xml file. Unexpectedly, I got this error while compiling the project.

> PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'base' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.BadLdapGrammarException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.ParseException: Encountered "#" at line 1, column 1.
>   Was expecting one of:
>       ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_STRING ...
>       LDAP_OID ...
>       " " ...

**ldap.properties**

```
url=ldap://test.example.com:389
base=DC=test,DC=example,DC=com
userDn=username
encryptedPassword=owakasdrlscdkdmmweils
```

**main.xml**

```xml
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="#{ldapProperties.url}" />
    <property name="base" value="#{ldapProperties.base}" />
    <property name="userDn" value="#{ldapProperties.userDn}" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
</bean>
```

How can I avoid this situation? Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is a parsing error : "`ParseException: Encountered "#"`" and it seems that variable substitution won't work with `#`, try to replace them with `$`, eg. `<property name="url" value="${ldapProperties.url}" />`

Comment: You're right but some features doesn't exist in Spring 2.5 like SPEL. Thank you for your help.